# Need assistance with Nested Loops and Dictionary in Python to display tabular data

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I have this sample data.

```
table_data = {
    "name": ['avery','john', 'jonas', 'jordan', 'terry', 'jared', 'evan'],
    "number": [0, 3, 8, 6, 12, 7, 11],
    "position": ['pg', 'sg', 'pf', 'pf', 'pg', 'c', 'sg'],
    "age": [25, 27, 29, 21, 22, 31, 27],
    "team": ['boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic', ],
            }
```

I want to display this data in tabular form with headings like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT8wL.png), of course without table borders.

In order to do that I used this code:

```
for items in table_data:
    i = 0
    while i <= len(table_data['name']):
        print(table_data['name'][i],
              table_data['age'][i],
              table_data['position'][i],
              table_data['team'][i],
              table_data['number'][i],)
        i += 1
    print()
```

it gave me this output:

```
john 27 sg boston celtic 3
jonas 29 pf boston celtic 8
jordan 21 pf boston celtic 6
terry 22 pg boston celtic 12
jared 31 c boston celtic 7
evan 27 sg boston celtic 11
```

Before I end, I would like you to know I am not really good with both dictionary and nested loops and I avoid both as much as possible.
PS - It's for learning purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that list indices start at 0, not 1, and end at (length of the list) - 1.

Comment: Note also that "Need assistance" is not a clear enough description of your problem. If you get an error, you should provide the complete error traceback. If you don't get the expected output, please make that clear and also provide your exact expected output.

Comment: I used i = 1 to provide a column with a serial number, but I messed up the code so many times and forgot to fix it. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gave me some errors, fixed those.

```
table_data = {
    "name": ['avery','john', 'jonas', 'jordan', 'terry', 'jared', 'evan'],
    "age": [25, 27, 29, 21, 22, 31, 27],
    "position": ['pg', 'sg', 'pf', 'pf', 'pg', 'c', 'sg'],
    "team": ['boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic', ],
    "number": [0, 3, 8, 6, 12, 7, 11]
            }
i = 0
while i < len(table_data):
    row = ""
    for k in table_data:
        row += f"{table_data[k][i]}\t"
    print(row)
    i += 1
```

I guess this is what you were looking for.

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to short this `table_data['name'][i]}\t` using indices part?

Comment: Iterate over the keys and generate the print value for each row --> row += f"{table_data[k][i]}\t", I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I would go about doing this:

```
table_data = {
    "name": ['avery', 'john', 'jonas', 'jordan', 'terry', 'jared', 'evan'],
    "number": [0, 3, 8, 6, 12, 7, 11],
    "position": ['pg', 'sg', 'pf', 'pf', 'pg', 'c', 'sg'],
    "age": [25, 27, 29, 21, 22, 31, 27],
    "team": ['boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic',
             'boston celtic', ],
}

for i in table_data["name"]:
    pos = table_data["name"].index(i)
    print(f"""{i}\t{table_data["age"][pos]}\t{table_data["position"][pos]}\t{table_data["team"][pos]}\t{table_data["number"][pos]}""")
```

Output:

```
avery   25  pg  boston celtic   0
john    27  sg  boston celtic   3
jonas   29  pf  boston celtic   8
jordan  21  pf  boston celtic   6
terry   22  pg  boston celtic   12
jared   31  c   boston celtic   7
evan    27  sg  boston celtic   11
```